# Heroku: docker entrypoint not found

Tags: docker, heroku, dockerfile, heroku-toolbelt, heroku-cli

I am trying to deploy a project on Heroku. I have set up bash entrypoint application, which is located in application root directory. Dockerfile content:

```
FROM node:10

# Create app directory
WORKDIR /usr/app

# Install app dependencies
# A wildcard is used to ensure both package.json AND package-lock.json are copied
# where available (npm@5+)
COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install
# If you are building your code for production
# RUN npm ci --only=production

# Bundle app source
COPY . .

RUN entrypoint.sh
```

When heroku tries to deploy, it fails when calling entrypoint in this line:

```
RUN entrypoint.sh
```

It says that entrypoint.sh is not found - although it is located in project directory and it is added to container. See project structure [here](https://github.com/matej2/reddit-vote-bot/tree/beta).

Answer (score 2):

You're using `RUN` instead of `ENTRYPOINT`.

- `RUN` means "run this command as part of build".
- `ENTRYPOINT` means "set this command as what happens when you do `docker run`."

Answer (score 1):

Use the ENTRYPOINT directive in docker file to set a script at entrypoint
`ENTRYPOINT ["./entrypoint.sh"]`
Also ensure it is executable (permissions)