# Docker VPN container unable to ping

Tags: docker, containers, ibm-cloud, vpn, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

The goal is to use a Docker container as proxy server when connected to VPN so that traffic can be redirected through the container.

I have the following Dockerfile.

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

RUN apt-get update -y

RUN apt-get install -y unzip \
    nano \
    iputils-ping \
    wget \
    telnet

COPY MotionPro_Linux_Ubuntu_x64_v1.2.5.sh /MotionPro_Linux_Ubuntu_x64_v1.2.5.sh

RUN chmod +x /MotionPro_Linux_Ubuntu_x64_v1.2.5.sh

RUN printf '%s\n' '#!/bin/bash' 'exit 0' | tee -a /etc/rc.local

RUN chmod +x /etc/rc.local

RUN sh /MotionPro_Linux_Ubuntu_x64_v1.2.5.sh
```

First question:

I am unable to install the application during image creation. However once inside the container I can execute the script with no issues.

Docker build output:

```
Uncompressing MotionPro Setup..........................................................................................................
./install.sh: 31: [: !=: unexpected operator
installing vpnd...
starting vpnd...
installing MotionPro...
creating desktop shortcut for MotionPro...
install MotionPro successfully.
```

vpnd seems to be the cause once starting the container because it is not started or something.

How can I solve this?

Question 2:

Starting the container like this:

```
docker run --name=motionpro -t -d --device=/dev/net/tun --cap-add=net_admin --privileged motionpro
```

I install the VPN application again and can succesfully connect but I can't ping any hosts on the vpn network.

Using netstat inside the container I can see that no routes are added once the vpn connection is successfull. Routes are normally added on my own host.

Comment: Look into the ENTRYPOINT directive. This was a similar problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59287314/heroku-docker-entrypoint-not-found/59287375#59287375

Comment: Is there a file install.sh in the container?  What is on line 31?
Are you saying that you docker exec to get in the container and execute: sh /MotionPro_Linux_Ubuntu_x64_v1.2.5.sh and it works ok?

Comment: Yes when executing the script with RUN it installs but when spinning up the container the vpn application doesn't work unless I execute it again. I think it installs a vpnd deamon that somehow can't start up with the container, but idk.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this issue regarding ping with the following docker run command:

```
docker run --hostname motionpro --name motionpro --privileged --network awxcompose_default --device /dev/net/tun --cap-add NET_ADMIN --sysctl net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=0 -t -d motionpro bash
```

It seems I had to disable IPv6.

Comment: and installing net-tools, iptables and iproute2